# Storing and retrieving 'level' data in a react-native video game application

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm developing a game with many levels. The data for the levels are around 1kb each, but I might have thousands of levels. These levels are generated outside of the game, using another script. I'm having a very difficult time figuring out what the best way to store this game data is. I'm trying in this first iteration of the app to have the data stored locally, which I might expand to e.g. a firebase solution later.

From my research it seems like these are my following options:

1. 'Swallow' the cost of loading a potentially large json file with a require directive, and the passing on the appropriate level data to a screen on level select (what I'm doing currently)
2. Have a script fill async storage with level data the first time the app is run, and then load level data from local storage.

What are my best options?

Comment: Saving in Async Storage is not an ideal solution as it requires deserialization every time you need to get a slice of level data which should be expensive for large complex file.

Comment: Can you split  levels data into multiple JSON files and fetch level data on demand - when user finish level and graduate to next level

Comment: You don't need specific database just save level JSON file to server and use Fetch API to fetch that on demand

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I guess I could fetch data on demand, but I'm looking at more of an offline-first app. So they should be able to play many games, if they were on e.g. a long flight. But I guess I could batch into multiple files of say "100" levels per file. Is there no canonical offline solution to this problem?

Comment: Experiment with add level data in Async Storage and serialization and deserialization cost. If not bad try use Async Storage

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you